# Minimizing an array-returning function using "fminunc"

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization, pid-controller

I am using MATLAB to build a code that does automatic tuning of the three PID controller gains. The way I am thinking of it, is to minimize the error (the difference between the desired state and the obtained one) of my system, for that, I coded a function that accepts the PID gains as input parameters and returns the calculated error, namely:

```
errors_vector = closedLoopSimulation(pidGains)
```

Since I have three set points (input commands), then the dimension of the output `errors_vector` is 3*N, where N is the number of time samples I have (1000 in my case). So that is the function I want to minimize, and for doing so, I tried using `fminunc` command, namely:

```
pidGains_ini  = [2.4 0.1 0.4];
func          = @closedLoopSimulation;
[pid, fval]   = fminunc(func, pidGains_ini)
```

However, when I run the last piece of code, I get this error:

```
User supplied objective function must return a scalar value.
```

which is clearly due to the fact that that `errors_vector` is a 3*1000 array and not a scalar.

My questions would be, from the programming point of view, is there a way that I can make `fminunc` minimize functions that return arrays?

On the other hand, and from the Control Theory point of view, is there another way which I can optimize the PID gains automatically?

I hope I made myself clear enough.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the errors_vector better? It's clear that there is an error for each time-step, but why are there three at each time-step? Are you controlling three outputs at the same time?

Comment: The [Ziegler-Nichols method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziegler–Nichols_method) and the [Relay method](http://www.controleng.com/search/search-single-display/relay-method-automates-pid-loop-tuning/4a5774decc.html) are two popular PID tuning schemes.

Comment: @tvo, yes this is what I am doing. My system is MIMO, having 3 input commands and 3 control efforts outputing from the PID controller.

Answer (score 1):

Minimizing a vector is not very well defined (there is something called multi-objective or multi-criteria optimization but that is somewhat specialized). "Normal" optimization methods can only minimize (or maximize) scalar objectives. I suspect in your case you could form such an objective by taking the sum of the squared errors and minimize that. To be complete: this is standard operating procedure and is often called "least squares".

Comment: What about using `lsqnonlin` in MATLAB? won't it work for my case specially that it works with functions returning arrays.

Comment: Yes, it will form the objective (sum of squares) for you automatically.